# How do i get the URL of the attribute ONCLICK using Xpath?

Tags: xpath

How can I extract the value of an attribute node via XPath?

Input  HTML  file is:

```
<tr class="evenrow" onclick="GoToLink('http://www.example.com/136.html');"></tr>
```

i wanna get this output : http://www.example.com/136.html

thank you for your help

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: i'm using this within a  scrapy project  , i have tried this : response.xpath('//tr[1]/@onclick').re('http:\/\/([^\/]+)([^.]+)\.html')

Comment: i think i found the solution to my problem response.xpath('//tr[1]/@onclick').re('http:[A-Z a-z 0-9 \/ .-]*')

Comment: If you want to use pure XPath see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer using a combination of substring-before and substring-after:

```
substring-before(substring-after(//tr/@onclick, "'"),"'")
```

Basically what it does is it takes the text inside the onclick attribute then substrings the URL between the `'` single quotes (for double quotes you'll need to adjust it).

Answer (score -1):

Try following one :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@onclick='GoToLink()']")).getText();
```

Hope it will help you.